# Ways to Implement Tomcat Server-Wide Persistent and Changeable Variables Across All WebApps

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, environment-variables

Production Environment: Tomcat 9 on CentOS 7 x64, mysql/mariadb 5.5x

Testing Environment: Tomcat 9 in Eclipse on Windows 7 x64, mysql 5.5x

I'm a Tomcat newbie looking for the best method to have server-wide variables readable/writable from all Webapps for things like MaintenanceMode(on/off) and MaintenanceMessage, etc.
These are the variable properties I'm looking for:

- Readable/writable from all instances of all java servlets on all webapps.
- Value persists after OS, Tomcat, or Webapp restart.
- I must be able to change the value of it from one webapp and then all other webapps recognize the change quickly, ideally without restarting.
- Ideally I wouldn't want to read the variable from disk on each server request. In case server is getting DDOSed or something.
- Ideally the solution is OS independent.
- If it's a disk file solution please recommend a place for me to store the file.

I'm new to Tomcat so some detail in any answers would be appreciated or links to detail. I'll probably be using a servlet on it's own 'admin' webapp that's only accessible through SSH-tunneling, etc, to set the variables. Then the public webapps would respond to any changes, like showing a maintenance message while I backup databases. I could also possibly change the variables using linux commands if needed.

If I stored the server variables in a database that could be fine but I wouldn't want to read the DB on every single request most likely, and when I change a variable I'd have to once again notify every webapp/servlet that something was changed and to re-read the DB.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What data-storage options are in play?

Comment: Christopher - I have a mysql/mariadb 5.5x database going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this recently in the form of "system messages", some of which are for maintenance. But the effect is the same. We had some additional "requirements" which helped us form the solution. These may or may not match up to your expectations/desires:

1. Multiple-server coordination
2. Immediate synchronization was not necessary

We used our relational database for the actual data storage. A single table with "system messages" and a few other fields such as when the messages became effective (`not_before DATETIME`) and when the messages became ineffective (`not_after DATETIME`).

On startup, the application reads the system messages table to find the currently-valid messages and stores them in `application` scope, including their validity dates. Whenever we want to show them on the screen, we check each item in memory and evict any that have expired. This is pretty fast.

Every X minutes (e.g. from `cron`), we make a request to a special servlet (on each server) that re-loads the system messages from the database. We protect that servlet by only allowing requests from certain IPs, so DOS is not an issue.

Not only can we add a system message from any server in the cluster, but we can also add one by writing directly to the database. That may be advantageous if you don't always want to use your application to generate these events.

You can change the value for X to anything as low as 1 (minute) if you are using `cron`. If you use some other kind of system, you can probably get updated even more often. I would seriously reconsider your requirement of "immediate" recognition because that requires a system that has much worse performance.

If you can guarantee that only your application can generate these changes, and you have a list of all other servers in the cluster somewhere, you could theoretically ping them all with the new message (or notify them that a new message exists and it's time to update their message-list), but that kind of thing is better-done with an orchestration tool such as Kubernetes, and we are getting a little out of scope IMO.

Comment: Christopher - Thanks. You gave me the idea that I could essentially do the same thing w/out cron by simply having each webapp query the server variables from the DB if it's been >X minutes since the last query. Now I need to find out the best way to store/change web-app scoped persistent variables across all requests. I think this is an easier task.

Comment: We used `cron` because having timer-based tasks in a web application seems architecturally stupid to me. It's also nice to be able to trigger any event any time I want, and not just when the timer goes off. Want to change the timer? Hmm... re-deploy the application or change the crontab?

Comment: As for where to put the data? Put it in the "application" scope -- the ServletContext. All requests have access to that, and it's shared. It's only shared within a single application, so if you have multiple web applications, they will have separate application-scopes and you'll need to just maintain them all separately.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider the cron approach too, but am a linux newbie too. But I can wait 5 mins for my purposes and can even change the next re-check time by adding another variable Time_To_Wait or something. Also I'll look into ServletContext for my variables. I've stored DB connections there so I'll figure it out. I haven't implemented anything yet but your approach is likely the answer.

Comment: Also, you're right, a timer in each servlet is a bad idea. I'll go with your special private servlet variable-updater method which is cleaner and you don't have to care about concurrency, etc.

Comment: Yikes, don't store database connections in the ServletContext. Instead, allow the container (Tomcat in this case) to maintain a database connection pool for your application. It's much safer and requires less code on your part. Head-over to the Tomcat users' mailing list if you have questions about how to do that.

Comment: BTW you still have to worry about concurrency, regardless of how you trigger the update. The best thing to do is to read the data from the database and then perform a single `ServletContext.setAttribute` call to replace the whole set of objects all at once. The ServletContext will protect itself from multi-threaded access. You code should consider previously-loaded data structures to be immutable. You might even want to wrap any data in an `UnmodifiableCollection` or some type (Map, List, Set, etc.... not sure what your data looks like).